# Non-invocable method error

Tags: c#, .net, wcf-ria-services

I try to use **SQL SERVER VIEW within RIA Services.**

So I created some view and updated EDMX.

Now I try to create some RIA Services method like

```
public IQueryable<ErrorsFullView> GetErrorsFullViews()
{
   return this.ObjectContext.ErrorsFullViews();
}
```

But get an error:

**Non-invocable member '.....ErrorsFullViews' cannot be used like a method.**

Any clue how it could be fixed?

Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

as the error says, `ErrorsFullViews` is not a method. Try to remove the parenthesis :

```
public IQueryable<ErrorsFullView> GetErrorsFullViews()
{
   return this.ObjectContext.ErrorsFullViews;
}
```